# where can i get this msvcrt_x64_vc8.lib?

Tags: windows

I am facing some linker error while compling the application(.exe) for 64 bit version.error says "libcmt.lib(wincrt0.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WinMain referenced in function __tmainCRTStartup".

So i came to know that i need to link the msvcrt_x64_vc8.lib .
can you suggest me,where can i get this lib?

Comment: Which compiler/ide are you using? VS 2005?

Answer (score 0):

You need this lib when compiling with VC8, in which case you already should have it. But did you install the 64 bit parts of VS2005 as well? Since they take extra disk space, they're optional.